# Is the voltage accurate?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, power-electronics

**The question is Find the Q-points for the diodes in the circuit using the ideal diode model:**
[image]

**The book solution is:**
[image]

However, per my analysis both diodes are conducting because if as assumed that D1 is cut off the voltage at D1 cathode side would be -3.92 V which is less than the voltage for the same diode anode side! Thus, since
VD1 (anode side) = 0 **-** VD1 (cathode side) = -3.92

0-(-3.92) = 3.92
D1 will conduct.
Am I right?

The Book is:

Microelectronic circuit design / Richard C. Jaeger, Travis N. Blalock. — 4th ed.
ISBN 978-0-07-338045-2

Comment: Determine which edition your book is and download an errata for it, and look up if the correct answer is there.

Comment: I'd certainly be looking at getting a new book.

Comment: Have all these questions been from the same book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, both diodes will conduct.